# Workflow Rule in Email alert

Tags: workflow

How to access the additional Emails box in the workflow email alert

{!$Setup.SomeCustomSetting__c.SomeField__c}

I want to access the field in additional email box template it is showing error

Error: Email addresses must be valid emails

Please anyone guide how the Vf template will go to the above address Guide me the answer
[image]

**I want Recipent type address as {!$Setup.SomeCustomSetting__c.SomeField__c} this one? How Please anyone guide me for the Answer**

Comment: How to access the Custom field in the vf email template,how to give the Value in additional email box

Comment: ok wait @AdrianLarson

Comment: You can't provide a merge field in Additional Emails; it has to be actual email addresses.

Comment: I want to access the custom setting feild of to address in receipent type how?